# Android Studio Right to Left ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been trying to make a ListView to work as RTL (Right to Left).
I've added the following line in the ListView and LinearLayout properties:

`android:layoutDirection="rtl"`

and it still shows the list from left to right.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Read this http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you all but I solved it with:

```
android:textDirection="rtl"
```

I've added it to the ListView and the layouts, and it worked. Next time you should try considering using this too for RTL layouts.

Answer (score 3):

To take advantage of RTL layout mirroring, simply make the following changes to your app:

Declare in your app manifest that your app supports RTL mirroring.
Specifically, add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the `<application>` element in your manifest file.

Change all of your app's `left/right` layout properties to new `start/end` equivalents.

- **If you are targeting your app to Android 4.2** (the app's
  `targetSdkVersion` or `minSdkVersion` is 17 or higher), then you should
  use `start` and `end` instead of `left` and `right`. For example,
  `android:paddingLeft` should become `android:paddingStart`.
- **If you want your app to work with versions earlier than Android 4.2**
  (the app's `targetSdkVersion` or `minSdkVersion` is 16 or less), then you
  should add `start` and `end` in addition to `left` and `right`. For
  example, you’d use both `android:paddingLeft` and `android:paddingStart`.

Comment: I've already done all this. It's still show the ListView from Left to Right.

Answer (score 2):

**RTL** layout support feature is supported on `Android 4.2(API level 17) or above only` . Please Add `android:layout_gravity="left/right"` in your parent Layout . And also allow **android:textAlignment**.

Set **`minSdkVersion=17`**

Please read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:layoutDirection

Comment: This hasn't changed anything in my view

Answer (score 0):

This will automatically adjust according to the device locale

```
android:textDirection="locale"
```